# ModalBarrier in Stack doesn't trigger GestureDetector

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Even if the `ModalBarrier` is wrapped with a `GestureDetector`, it doesn't trigger taps outside the `Container`. But replace `ModalBarrier` with `Container` and it works.

The `Container` becomes a workaround but why doesn't it work with `ModalBarrier`?

Here's the code:

```
return GestureDetector(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
      onTap: _onDropdownTap(),
      child: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: [
          ModalBarrier(
            color: Colors.black26,
          ),
          Positioned(
            left: width/2 - cardWidth/2,
            top: height/2 - cardHeight/2,
            width: dropdownWidth,
            height: dropdownHeight,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```